# Android Wearable app with no Activity

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

I'm creating a wear app that is used to extend my handheld app's notifications.
I wrote a wear module (a separate wear app) because I needed my handheld  and wearable devices to behave differently with their notifications.

By creating a separate app for wear, it can now be launched on my wear device (by default, I get the Activity saying "Hello Square World!").

Is there a way for my wear app to exists without the option to launch it?

Comment: what does the app need to do, you can probably get a way with using a service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As tyczj stated you don't need an activity if you are using service.

To be able to run/debug this via Android Studio you must edit the Run/Debug configuration for the wear app and specify "Do not launch activity" under the Activity section.

Here's a sample of my manifest, it's just a wear listener service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.codechimp.myapp" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >

        <service android:name=".WearListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I am not able to run the wear app without an activity. I get an "Default Activity not found" error

Comment: Can you explain how you are trying to run the wear app.  If you are using a service to launch an activity then the activity needs to be in the manifest but without the launcher or default intents.

Comment: OK, so this worked, but only after I went to "Edit configuration", and under "Activity" I chose "Do not launch Activity". Please add this to your answer and I'll accept it

Comment: The Edit Configuration is a visual way to specify the activity does not have the intents mentioned.  I have updated the manifest/description to reflect this.

Comment: I don't understand... why did you add the NonDefaultActivity? it is not needed to achieve an app with no default Activity.

Comment: I added the non default activity based on your earlier comment where it sounded like you wanted to launch an activity from an intent within the service.

Comment: No... I don't want an Activity in the app at all. I just wanted you to address "Edit configuration" because (for me) Android Studio did not allow the app to compile until I checked "Do not launch Activity"

Comment: Got you now, I was thinking about a deployed app, not running in the IDE.  Modified answer for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 3.1.2,

1. Click "Edit Configurations"

[image: Edit Configurations]

2. Select "wear" module and select "Nothing" for Launch options.

[image: Select Nothing]